# How to perform a few operations between the time range?

Tags: javascript, time, range

I am getting the time information from an API call. Say, the output is:

```
[
  {
    "ItemID": 7,
    "URL": "http://localhost/img/seven.png",
    "StartTime": "05:00:00"
  },
  {
    "ItemID": 12,
    "URL": "http://localhost/img/twelve.png",
    "StartTime": "14:45:00"
  },
  {
    "ItemID": 16,
    "URL": "http://localhost/img/sixteen.png",
    "StartTime": "17:30:00"
  }
]
```

And I also have a timer running in my browser, which executes a particular code every second. For a range of the time starting from the API's callback, say, "14:45:00" till "14:50:00", for 300 seconds.

I am not sure what should I code to achieve it. I already tried something, which happens for that moment so, I just check the time and then alert. This is what I have till now:

```
setInterval(function () {
  var curDate = new Date();
  var curTime = curDate.getTime();
  /*
    For a range of the time starting from the API's callback,
    say, "14:45:00" till "14:50:00", for 300 seconds.
    I am not sure what should I code to achieve it.
    I already tried something, which happens for that moment
    so, I just check the time and then alert.
  */
  // Moment Code
  $.each(items, function (i, v) {
    var curTimeString = curDate.getHours() + ":" + ("0" + curDate.getMinutes()).slice(-2) + ":" + ("0" + curDate.getSeconds()).slice(-2);
    if (curTimeString == v.StartTime)
      alert("Started!");
  });
  console.log(curTime); // Number of seconds from Jan 1, 1970.
}, 1000);
```

Please guide me how should I proceed.